# Node.JS: What happens to postdata when client request is interrupted?

Tags: node.js, http, post, error-handling

In [the Node.JS docs for HTTP](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) (v0.8.20), under `ServerRequest`, I see events for `data` and `end`. I do not see an event for `error`.

Normally, if there was an interruption while receiving data, I could detect it by looking at `error`. But will that work for postdata?

How can I be sure whether have received the entire postdata, and that it was not truncated due to network failure?

Answer (score 1):

I have not confirmed this with actual running code, but just looking at the manual, [http.ServerRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverrequest) is a [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream) and that has *Event: 'error'* documented.

Answer (score 1):

there's been a recent issue on this: https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4775

in general, you should always listen for and handle errors from any streams and eventemitters